# Match pattern midline and insert newline in awk

Tags: regex, awk

Have been trying to use `awk` and its `gensub()` to match a pattern not at the beginning of a line and insert newline between the first part and the match.

The pattern is to match MM/DD HH:MM:SS.

My script `splitatdate.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
  if ( /.+[0-9][0-9][/][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] / ) {
    print gensub(/^\(.+\)\([0-9][0-9][/][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] \)/,"\\1\n\\2", "g")
  }
}
```

My test input `break-me.txt`, which contains a sample of the line types I have:

```
11/25 08:06:30 good text follows here
rs = ['yada yada11/25 08:07:41 more interesting stuff
rs = ['things with data: tag value
rs = ['yada yada data: 11/25 08:07:43 even more interesting stuff
```

What I get when I run in bash: `splitatdate.awk break-me.txt` is:

```
rs = ['yada yada11/25 08:07:41 more interesting stuff
rs = ['yada yada data: 11/25 08:07:41 even more interesting stuff
```

which is matching the correct lines (those not starting with the date stuff) but is not inserting the new line or, as far as I can tell, doing any substitution.

What I thought I was going to get:

```
rs = ['yada yada
11/25 08:07:41 more interesting stuff
rs = ['yada yada data: 
11/25 08:07:41 even more interesting stuff
```

The full task is to echo every line as is, but split with newline those that have the date string not at the beginning. But I need to understand why this part isn't working. I'm not hung up on using awk if someone has a better tool, but would like to know what I've done wrong.

This is on RHEL 6 with GNU awk 3.1.7.

Edit: Answer for this script: Leave off the backslashes before the capture grouping parens inside gensub().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the backslashes before the capture group parens - just use `(..)`, not `\(..\)` since the latter is literal parens.

You might want to use this instead though so you don't have to specify the regexp twice:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.+)([0-9][0-9][/][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9](:[0-9][0-9]){2}.*)/,a) { print a[1] "\n" a[2]  }' file
rs = ['yada yada
11/25 08:07:41 more interesting stuff
rs = ['yada yada data:
11/25 08:07:43 even more interesting stuff
```

Its GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() but you were using gawk anyway.

Comment: Removing the backslashes in my .awk script worked. Thanks.

Comment: But copy/pasting your example with 'match()' returns no output for me.

Comment: You are using an EXTREMELY old gawk (I think mine is old and I'm on 4.1.3!), get an updated one as you are missing a ton of very useful functionality, including this apparently, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History. Hmm, that says the 3rd arg for match() was introduced in 3.1 and it should have given you a syntax error if match() didn't support it so idk. The ONLY way that script would output NOTHING is if the regexp didn't match your input data so try it with a simpler regexp to debug.

Comment: Ah, I got it - RE intervals like `{2}` were disabled by default in older gawks - add the `--re-interval` flag at the start of the script (`awk --re-interval '...'`) or change `(:[0-9][0-9]){2}` to the explicit equivalent `:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]`. Most importantly though - **get a new version of gawk!**

Comment: Yes, indeed. RHEL 6 uses old versions of things because They Want to be Stable, for better or worse.  In this case I'm stuck using what comes with the OS.
Adding `--re-interval` generated the output as you said. Thanks much.

I'll have to be careful using online help guides to make sure they're not talking about features in v>3.1.7 if there are that many new features. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed -r 's|^(.+)([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}.*)$|\1\n\2|' infile
11/25 08:06:30 good text follows here
rs = ['yada yada
11/25 08:07:41 more interesting stuff
rs = ['things with data: tag value
rs = ['yada yada data: 
11/25 08:07:43 even more interesting stuff
```

This captures whatever is before the date string in the first capture group and everything starting with the date string in the second capture group, then inserts a newline.

To guarantee that a line doesn't start with the date string, we require at least one character before it with `.+` ("one or more of whatever").

Comment: This solves the real problem I had of splitting the lines and echoing the unchanged lines. And nice to use different regexp delimiter instead of '/'. I couldn't see how to do that in awk.